# Vanishing of a sum of roots of unity

Tags: nt.number-theory, matrices, cv.complex-variables, roots-of-unity

In my answer to [this question](https://mathoverflow.net/q/420359), there appears the following sub-question about a sum of roots of unity. Denoting $z=\exp\frac{i\pi}N$ (so that $z^N=-1$), can the quantity
$$\sum_{k=0}^{N-1}z^{2k^2+k}$$
vanish ?

The answer is clearly **No** for $N\le7$. I suspect that it never vanishes, which should answer definitively the above matricial question. Any idea of a general argument ?

Comment: Numerically, it seems like the sum tends towards $\sqrt{N/2}+2^{-3/2}(-1)^{N}$ to pretty good accuracy. I suspect it should be possible to prove something like this using some clever number theoretic argument, maybe. At least a lower bound of the form $a\sqrt{N}$ with $0<a<2^{-1/2}$ should be quite doable, though I'm not seeing how at the moment.

Comment: This is close to a Gauss sum, but not quite (summation up to $N-1$ instead of $2N-1$). One can try to work in the ring $R=\mathbb{Z}[z]/(2)$ (reduction mod 2). If $S$ denotes the sum in question, then in $R$ we have $S^2 = \sum_{k=0}^{N-1} \zeta_N^{2k^2+k}$ with $\zeta_N=z^2$. This last sum is a [generalized quadratic Gauss sum](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quadratic_Gauss_sum#Generalized_quadratic_Gauss_sums). If $N$ is odd then it can be computed and it seems that some power of it is an odd integer, hence $S \neq 0$. This probably doesn't work for $N$ even.

Comment: @FrançoisBrunault Raising to a higher power of $2$ makes the calculation easier. See my resposne.

Comment: @GHfromMO's [response](https://mathoverflow.net/a/420494) referenced [above](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/420473/vanishing-of-a-sum-of-roots-of-unity#comment1080054_420473).

Answer (score 15, accepted):

For general $N$, we can reason by induction on the $2$-adic valuation of $N$. If $N$ is odd, GH from MO's answer shows that $S_N :=\sum_{k=0}^{N-1} \zeta_{2N}^{2k^2+k} \neq 0$, where $\zeta_{2N} = z = e^{\pi i/N}$ is a primitive $2N$-th root of unity. The same argument shows that for any odd $N$ and any $b \neq 1$, the following variant of $S_N$ is nonzero:
\begin{equation*}
S_{N,b} :=\sum_{k=0}^{N-1} \zeta_{2N}^{2^b k^2+k} \neq 0.
\end{equation*}
For convenience of the reader, the proof goes as follows. In the ring $\mathbb{Z}[z]/(2)$, we have
\begin{equation*}
S_{N,b}^{2^{b+3}} = \sum_{k=0}^{N-1} z^{2^{b+3} (2^b k^2+k)} = \sum_{k=0}^{N-1} \zeta_N^{2^{2b+2} k^2+2^{b+2} k} = \sum_{k=0}^{N-1} \zeta_N^{(2^{b+1} k + 1)^2 - 1} = \zeta_N^{-1} \sum_{\ell=0}^{N-1} \zeta_N^{\ell^2},
\end{equation*}
and one conclude as in GH from MO's answer.

Now write $N=2^a M$ with $M$ odd, and assume $a \geq 1$. The Galois group of $\mathbb{Q}(\zeta_{2N})/\mathbb{Q}(\zeta_N)$ is of order 2, generated by the automorphism $\sigma : \zeta_{2N} \mapsto \zeta_{2N}^{1+N} = - \zeta_{2N}$. Moreover, we have
\begin{equation*}
\sigma(S_{N,b}) = \sum_{k=0}^{N-1} (-\zeta_{2N})^{2^b k^2+k} = \sum_{k=0}^{N-1} (-1)^k \zeta_{2N}^{2^b k^2+k},
\end{equation*}
so that
\begin{equation*}
\frac12 (S_{N,b}+\sigma(S_{N,b})) = \sum_{\substack{k=0 \\ k \textrm{ even}}}^{N-1} \zeta_{2N}^{2^b k^2+k} = \sum_{k=0}^{N/2-1} \zeta_{2N}^{2^{b+2} k^2+2k} = \sum_{k=0}^{N/2-1} \zeta_N^{2^{b+1} k^2+k} = S_{N/2, b+1}.
\end{equation*}
By induction, we have $S_{N/2,b+1} \neq 0$, which implies $S_{N,b} \neq 0$.

Comment: Thanks for working out the general case. I rewrote my answer several times. I had a version with Galois conjugates, a version with residue calculation, a version where I suspected the generalization for general $N$, a version were I thought I generalized for general $N$, and finally the clean short version for odd $N$. Your ideas are very nice, and your answer should be accepted.

Comment: @GHfromMO. I hesitated to accept either solution, because both of you contributed significantly to the complete solution of the question. But if you suggest that François' answer be accepted, I'll follow you.

Comment: @DenisSerre Good that you accepted François' answer. The main ideas are his. He started the solution, and he finished it. I only contributed an intermediate calculation, which is rather standard.

Answer (score 12):

The sum does not vanish when $N$ is odd. I will elaborate on François Brunault's [idea](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/420473/vanishing-of-a-sum-of-roots-of-unity#comment1080000_420473).

Assume that $N$ is odd, and let $S$ be the sum in question. Working in the ring $\mathbb{Z}[z]$, we see that $S^{16}\equiv T\pmod{2}$, where
$$T:=\sum_{k=0}^{N-1}e^{16\pi i(2k^2+k)/N}=e^{-2\pi i/N}\sum_{k=0}^{N-1}e^{2\pi i(4k+1)^2/N}=e^{-2\pi i/N}\sum_{\ell=0}^{N-1}e^{2\pi i\ell^2/N}.$$
The $\ell$-sum is a classical Gauss sum whose fourth power is known to be $N^2$. Therefore, $S^{64N}\equiv T^{4N}=N^{2N}\equiv 1\pmod{2}$, and hence $S\neq 0$ as claimed.

Comment: Thanks! Meanwhile, building on this, I give an argument for general $N$, which I think is ok with your previous argument, and should also be ok with your new argument.

Comment: I confirm that your argument works to show the non-vanishing of the sum $S_{N,b}$ in my answer for odd $N$. For clarity I included the argument in my answer.